# Virtual hosts configuration with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, wamp, symfony4, virtualhost

I have a problem with my virtual host on WAMP server. I tested projects that I worked on before, and they all work.

When I hit my localhost name of the project

```
127.0.0.1 project.local
```

defined in my hosts file, it returns

> This page isn’t working

It's my first Symfony 4 project and I think my virtual hosts configuration may not be right.

This is my project skeleton:

[iproject-skeleton-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uuij.jpg)

And my virtual host config:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName project.local
     DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/project/public"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/project/public/">
           AllowOverride All
           Order Allow,Deny
           Allow from All
           <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
             Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
               RewriteEngine On
               RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
               RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
           </IfModule>
       </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you follow the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html)?  And how confident are your that INSTALL_DIR is being set to the expected value?  Might try replacing it with the actual path just to be sure.  Use the Symfony development server to verify your app is working and check the apache logs.

Comment: Zone .local isn't good enough since it mDNS/zeroconf standard.

Comment: Are you using Apache 2.2 or 2.4? If 2.4 change `Order Allow,Deny Allow from All` to `Require local` the 2.4 syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the apache-pack in your project.

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```